# Is there any reason to use Gradle if I'm just writing programs for myself?

Tags: java, gradle

Are there any benefits to using Gradle if I'm already using a modern IDE if I'm **not part of a team, just writing JavaFX and Android programs for myself**?

My previous question got closed as non constructive, I believe it's a legitimate question. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the number of people working on a project has much relevancy to whether or not you should use a build tool. So I think the question is a big off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the fact the how many developers working, do you have any requirements from the following?

Gradle can **automate the building**, **testing**, **publishing**, **deployment** and more of software packages or other types of projects such as generated static websites, generated documentation or indeed anything else

If you have any requirement of above highlighted and project is big enough that you can't live happy with either ant scripts etc., (or) IDE provided build scripts, then you need Gradle type of tools. If you are on just learning type of project having this tool may help in learning those automation steps. This tools is not a mandatory one for web projects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also consider not writing tests for your own code?

Personally, I use gradle for all new projects, it gets you going very quickly, particularly if you stick with the default src dir structures, so it's not an overhead, just create a simple build.gradle and both your source and tests are sorted. I also use eclipse, but make gradle generate the project settings, so I only have to worry about jar dependencies in one place.

I find it's much better to get into the habit of using the same tooling whether you're doing personal projects or in part of a team.